# Where is the app/ oder mobile/ directory

Tags: android, android-studio, google-cloud-messaging

I want to implement GCM in my android app following these instrudoctiones:
https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client
Under the section "Add the configuration file to your project" they say, that you have to copy the configuration file to your projects app/ oder mobile/ directory.
But I can't find these directories. And the terminal command also claims, that there is no such directory. Do I have to create them, or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you pushing it to the right place?

Comment: Which folders are there inside your project folder in the workspace?

Comment: There are just the .gradle, .idea, build, some extern libraries and of course my module

@JoxTraex what is the right place?

Comment: When you enter the command line are you making sure that you are in the right directory, a workspace still maps to a place on your hard drive, navigate to the right directory.

Comment: I am in my project directory. But the problem is, there is no app/ or mobile/ directory, and I don't know where to find them

Comment: Place it on your module directory than. `app` is the default module name created be Android Studio. But in your case it's different.

Comment: You mean the configuration file, or the terminal?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your Android Studio? Most interested in the cookie crumbs for the path.

Comment: Screenshot of which part of Android Studio?
The Terminal?

I tried it like Prerak Sola suggested, and pasted it in the module directory, maybe it will work.

Answer (score 0):

When you get the `google-services.json` file, you just need to do these:

Click `Android` tap on the top in Android studio, and choose `Project`:

[image]

Then, just copy `google-services.json` file to `app` folder and you are done.

[image]

Comment: Problem was, that there was no "app" folder. Apperently it had the folder had the name of my app, so I copied it there like suggested by Prerak Sola and it worked.

Comment: Yup just for your main project folder

Comment: I think the terminology used in Android Studio is the app/mobile folder is the "Module" folder. Without looking I am willing to bet there are numerous examples of someone starting a project and naming their module app. This is just my guess.